# Android: Custom CursorAdapter to alternate resources

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-cursoradapter, alternate

This problem has been stuck for a while in my head.

What I need to do:
Show a listview with alternating resources for the items in the listView.

What is my problem:
So far I can alternate resources and show no data, or show the data but not alternate resources. The first item works well every time, but not form there onwards. I think I'm very close but I just can't think what is going wrong...

What have I done:
I have used a custom simple cursor adapter.

Where is the code:

```
public class DialogCursor extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

private LinearLayout wrapper;
private TextView burbuja;

  public DialogCursor(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
        int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}



@Override 
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  

    View row = convertView;

    if (row == null) {


        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogo_row, parent, false);

    }
    burbuja = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.idiomaselec);
    wrapper = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.wrapper);

   //get reference to the row
   View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent); 
   Log.d("Dialogo","enters getview");
   Log.d("Dialogo",Integer.toString(position));
   //check for odd or even to set alternate colors to the row background
   if(position % 2 == 0){  
    Log.d("Dialogo","Even");
    burbuja.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_green);
    wrapper.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
   }
   else {
    Log.d("Dialogo","not even");
    burbuja.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_yellow);
    wrapper.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);  
   }

   return row; 
  }
```

}

The cursor adapter is called from this other class (just showing relevant part)

String[] from = new String[] { DialogoTable.TABLE_DIALOGO + "." + columna };

// Fields on the UI to which we map
  final int[] to = new int[] { R.id.idiomaselec};

```
Log.d("Dialogo","entra en fillData2");
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
if (bot)  {
    Log.d("Dialogo","entra en fillData2.5");
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
}

adapter2 = new DialogCursor(this, R.layout.dialogo_row, null, from, to, 0);

setListAdapter(adapter2);
```

And the output:
If I return row (last line of code)
I get the background resources in the right place but with no data
If I return view (last line of code)
I get the data but only the first item has the right background resources.

One last note:
I have followed this example
http://adilsoomro.blogspot.com/2012/12/android-listview-with-speech-bubble.html
but I dont want to create a class message since I wnat the data from my DB.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

In a similar case I was able to have a custom cursorAdapter alternate resources based on the cursor position.  I put the following code in my bindView where entryView is the passed in view.  I am overriding getView at all.

```
if(cursor.getPosition()%2 == 1){
     entryView.findViewById(R.id.title_relative).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
}else{
     entryView.findViewById(R.id.title_relative).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
}
```